# AsyncTask postExecute or onCancelled not getting called when android kills Background tasks- No more background processes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I m running a queue where  i m downloading videos and for que to work properly in need to get the postExecute of AsyncTask called mandatorily..or there must b an event where i can get when  my asynctask is getting killed by the processor which says "No more Background Tasks"..Low memory..OnCancelled not getting called too...Any help???

---

@kdehairy Intent Service??? Okk actually i need to update my UI..For example i have a video being downloaded which started in asynctask and i keep track of the chunk and accordingly update my custom progressBar if the user destroys the activity m not cancelling my ansynctask till my work is done..i keep track of asynctask..if for some reason my asynctask stops even if its in background...it agains ques the task..which is done by service...what i m saying is even i dont know my asynctask is queued from service or app...but i just kip track of asyncatsks being queued..and push and pop from stack..asynctask postexecute refreshes my view...like in if asynctask is running from service i check in postExecute if my UI screen is visible...and than i call new Intent..with Flags SingleTop and New Task and thus i can refresh my progressBar..Can i update my UI using IntentService..will it run on UIThread or worker thread..

Can u provide me an example...???
Thanks Kdehairy

Comment: call this **android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());** when you want to kill your service or activity.

Comment: I dont want to kill my service or activity but want to get notified when aynstask is killed or finsished as in case of postExecute...which not always gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is critical for you to handle the life cycle of your process, then it is better to use a service.
AsyncTask is not a system component (Services are).

#### UPDATE:

1. extend the `IntentService` with your own implementation.
2. to update the UI you can use boradcasts. as follow:

   1. *whenever you need to update your UI, wirte this in your service:*

      ```
      Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_PROGRESS);
      intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, currentValue);
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
      ```

      Here we are sending a broadcast using the `LocalBroadcastManager` because we want to keep this broadcast private to the application.
   2. *in your Activity:*

      ```
      // this is the broadcast receiver object that will handle our UI updates.
      private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              int position = intent.getIntExtra(YourService.EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
              // do your UI updates here.
          }
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
          // register for the broadcast.
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
              mReceiver,
              new IntentFilter(YourService.ACTION_UPDATE_PROGRESS));
          super.onResume();
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
          // unregister when activity is paused.
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(PlayerActivity.this)
              .unregisterReceiver(mPlayerReceiver);
          super.onPause();
      }
      ```

If you find anything unclear, please let me know.

Comment: actually I am using a service only...but i m using a que of asynctasks from service which when destroyed i m queing the asynctasks back...But thing is the sequence of my que hampers if asynctask stops without postExecute where my code for nextItem is written

Comment: AsyncTask must be used from the UIThread as you may know. so using it within a service is somewhat tricky and not recommended. if you want to queue some tasks in a thread within a service, use the `IntentService`. It is an implementation of the Service that handles the queuing and thread creation for you. it's just as easy as the AsyncTask, but more appropriate for services. let me know if it did not work for you.

Comment: Service is no diff process or thread as per docs...it uses the main worker thread...I just start AsyncTask..as Name signifies isnt a Asynctask independent thread...how does it matters if i start from a Service or Activity??? I dont know what m i saying??? Is my concept wrong on threads??I need to learn plzz help me

Answer (score 0):

try like this.. or look at this example it migth help you.. **call onCancle() method where you want.. as shown in Onpause() in below example, It ll cancel the asyncTask**

```
public class newA extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "MyPost";

private boolean post_is_running = false;

private doSomethingDelayed doSth;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button pushButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button);
    pushButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (post_is_running) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Stopping Async Task onPause");
        doSth.cancel(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (post_is_running) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Async Task onResume");
        doSth = (doSomethingDelayed) new doSomethingDelayed().execute();
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText("Resuming..");
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (post_is_running == false) {
        post_is_running = true;
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Async Task onClick");
        doSth = (doSomethingDelayed) new doSomethingDelayed().execute();
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText("Starting..");
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Stopping Async Task onClick");
        post_is_running = false;
        doSth.cancel(true);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText("Stopping..");
    }
}

private class doSomethingDelayed extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private int num_runs = 0;

    private JSONObject holder;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... gurk) {

        while (!this.isCancelled()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "going into postData");

            long ms_before = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            Log.v(TAG, "Time Now is " + ms_before);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                postData();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long ms_after = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            long time_passed = ms_after - ms_before;

            Log.v(TAG, "coming out of postData");
            Log.i(TAG, "RTT: " + time_passed + " ms");

            num_runs++;

            if (!this.isCancelled()) {
                publishProgress(num_runs, (int) time_passed);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "request is send every 5 sec.";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button))
                .setText("Stopped. Tap to Start for sending new request!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... num_runs) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Looped with time interval in every 5 sec "
                + num_runs[0].toString() + " Times";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast.makeText(context,
                text + "\nRTT: " + num_runs[1].toString() + " ms", duration)
                .show();

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText(text
                + "\nTap to Stop process");

    }

    public void postData() {

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/listen");

        String resp = null;
        long time_passed = 0;

        // Sending details in Json Format

        holder = new JSONObject();

        try {
            holder.put("UserId", "1");
            holder.put("TimeStamp", "12345");
            System.out.println("----holder--" + holder);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            resp = response.toString();
            String t = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "RTT inside post-data: " + time_passed);

        Log.i(TAG, resp.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this was not my Question...i m not trying to cancel my asynctask...U know about TaskKillers...or when low memory android kills all your background apps without any info...It kills my running asyncstask without informing me..even services...Hopw u understand my Qn..